# Why is sed failing when using two variables?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

sed fails with the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 72: unterminated `s' command
```

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD="$(cat /etc/fstab | grep /tmp)"
NEW="$(cat /etc/fstab | grep /tmp | sed 's/,noexec//')"
sed "s|$OLD|$NEW|" /etc/fstab
```

I don't see how it is unterminated, I have 3 `|` symbols as delimiters and am using double quotes since I have variables in the statement.

I have read many other questions on stack overflow and other blogs that are similar, but none that were using two variables like this.

Edit to show fstab:

```
LABEL=/boot    /boot    xfs    defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec    1    2
/dev/mapper/LV_tmp    /tmp    xfs    nodev,noexec    1    2
proc    /proc    proc    defaults    0    0
```

Comment: What is in `$OLD` and `$NEW`? Your `sed "s|$OLD|$NEW|"` command contains variables. You might not see any `/`s there, but they may be there.

Comment: Or [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed)

Comment: There are `/`s, which is why I use `|` as a delimiter

Comment: Ok, but there may be `|`s, too.

Comment: There are not. It is an fstab file like the original post says. I have also tried `@` as a delimiter

Comment: Can you supply the content of your fstab or enough to reproduce as there are many versions of fstab.

Comment: [Not repro](https://ideone.com/GF5cOz).

Comment: Please run your script with `bash -x yourscript` to geta helpful debug log